# Transition to Large Title from Small title shows small title for a moment in the destination view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, large-title

I have two view controller in a navigation controller. The root view controller has small title and the next view controller has large title.

When I push the next view controller, I set

> self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always

In the viewDidLoad of next view controller. The problem is, when transitioning it shows the title as small for a moment and then the title becomes big. But I just want to show the big title. I tried setting the title text in ViewDidAppear, it kind of works but the title appears late. I don't want that too.

Comment: Put the code in viewDidLoad and see that it works.

Comment: @bhatejaud I already mentioned in question that the code is in the viewDidLoad. and I also tried setting `largeTitleDisplayMode` before pushing the nextViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Say you are doing something like this in vc1

```
let vc2 = SomeVC()
vc2.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
```

So try to set the property before pushing the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I did this :

In VC 1 :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
}
```

In VC 2 :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```